# Undefined layout resource error, but resource does exists

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, xamarin.android, xamarin

Im following this tutorial : http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/list_view

I have `list_item.xml` under `HelloListView/Resources/layout/`

Im referencing the XML file as a parameter below:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Resource.Layout.list_item, countries);
    // ...
}
```

**Build Error**

> 'HelloListView.Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for
>   'list_item'

I followed the few steps from the tutorial verbatim. What am I missing here?

**In Addition**

If I add the file to `Resources/layout/` by right-clicking `layout/` and `Add`ing an XML file, it will not allow me to edit the source -- as in, I click the Source tab, and there is no cursor and I cannot type in the window.

If I add the file to the solution, then make the changes to the XML file as needed, then move the file into `Resources/layout/`, this still doesn't work (as @CheeseBaron mentioned, it isn't added to the `Resource.Designer.cs`)

**Quick Fix**

After adding the XML via right-clicking `layout/`, and facing the issue described above, I edited the file *outside* of MonoDevelop (used Notepad++), which triggered the `Resource.Designer.cs` to reload with the generated ID for `list_item`. Definitely not ideal.

Comment: Try renaming it to list_item.axml instead.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yup, I tried that as well, but to no avail.

Comment: Tried checking whats in Resource.Designer.cs? If you added the file correctly it should appear in there as well.

Comment: Also what is the build action on the list_item.xml file? Set it to AndroidResource if it isn't already.

Comment: @CheeseBaron I've added the answer to your first question as an update to my post. Also, the build action is set to `AndroidResource`.